# Uninstall App from device

Tags: android, arraylist

I want to remove app from device, as i perform uninstall , app must removed from the ArrayList and update the app drawer like wise.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED);
filter.addDataScheme("package");
registerReceiver(new RefreshApps(), filter);

}

public class RefreshApps extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(context, "App Installed/Removed" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find out that an app is being removed via a BroadcastReceiver listening for ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED.  You can find out one has been installed by listening for  ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED.  Obviously these work for anything except your own app.

Comment: thank you sir, uninstall is working and BroadcatReceiver is also called but the app i uninstalled is still showing in app drawer , how to remove that ?